# On IBM i (AS/400, iSeries) what is DW4 and DW5 data storage?

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

What is DW4 and DW5 data storage? On the following web page about IBMs Query/400 product under General operating characteristics, it mentions "Accessibility from DW4 and DW5 for data merge."

[IBMs Query for i5/OS V6.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/printableversion.wss?docURL=/common/ssi/rep_sm/1/877/ENUS5761-QU1/index.html)

Comment: It's IBM's DisplayWrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DW4 and DW5 refer to [IBM's DisplayWrite word processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_DisplayWrite), versions 4 and 5. It's extremely unlikely that you'll ever run into any DW uses. (But if you're still using something as old as Query/400, I suppose it's possible.)